# Is there a iOS Configuration Profile Key for "Find My iPhone?"

Tags: iphone, ios, mdm

I've been looking at this page:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html

for the configuration profile keys. I couldn't find one for the feature "Find My iPhone." Is there a key for that? If so what is it?

Comment: I'm trying to set that feature to "On" in the profile I push to my iPhones.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but both Michael and titaniumdecoy are only partially correct. The "Find My iPhone" app is an app that helps you locate your iOS device if you have the settings set in your iCloud settings on the device.

I too would be interested in knowing if it is possible to push out a configuration profile (using IPCU) that has the "Find My iPhone" setting locked on even though it is technically an iCloud user settings.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @titaniumdecoy (and +1 to him).

If you are trying to push "Find My iPhone" onto all your iPhone(s) and you have more than just 3 or 4 iPhones to manage, maybe you can use something like Apple's [iPhone Configuration Utility for Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466) to install the app onto all the iPhones you have control over.